# Autopopulate hidden form inputs

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I have this dropdown, I need the value to be passed to a hidden modal form using a javascript. I'm currently stuck here. Any ideas on the script.

```
                    <!-- Adress dropdown-->

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                    <select class="form-control" name="adress" id="adress">
                    <option value="">Select Adress</option>
                    <option value="1">HRA</option>
                    <option value="2">Lavington</option>
                    <option value="3">Krishna Plaza</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

here is my hidden input field on my modal form

```
  <!--hidden input-->
 <input type="text" name="adress1" id="adress1"  class="id" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var hiddenInput = document.querySelector("#adress1");
var select = document.querySelector("#adress");

hiddenInput.value = select.value;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's 

long-term value.

Comment: I added an on change jQuery event . And again thanks for your responses